# Jquery not triggering for the change(function())

Tags: magento2, shipping, jquery

```
jQuery('input[name^="ko_unique_"]').trigger("change");
        
        jQuery('input[name^="ko_unique_"]').change(function() {
        var v = jQuery(this).val();
        console.log(v);
        if(v == 'simpleshipping_simpleshipping'){
            console.log('check');
            jQuery('#deliv-hold').show();
        }
        else{
            jQuery('#deliv-hold').hide();
        }
        });
```

The above-mentioned code is working fine on the console but when it is used in js. it does not execute after the second line.

Comment: you have to try with `if(jQuery.trim(v) == 'simpleshipping_simpleshipping')`. and check that

Comment: It is not printing the value of v in the console i.e., only the first two lines are working. after thats it exits

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.on()` instead of traditional `.change()` event,

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name^="ko_unique_"]', function(e) {
/* your code here */
}
```